# simplifying Excel formula currently using INDEX, ROW, SUMPRODUCT and IFERROR

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

Does anyone have any brilliant ideas to simplify this difficult formula? Don't panic when you see it, I will try to explain.

> =IFERROR(INDEX(rangeOfDesiredValues,(1/SUMPRODUCT((rangeOfSerials=$D20)*(rangeOfApps=cfgAppID)*(rangeOfAccessIDs=cfgAccessID)*ROW(rangeOfDesiredValues))^-1)),"")

Currently I am using SUMPRODUCT to do the equivalent of a VLOOKUP with multiple columns as criteria. Usually that only works with number results, but since I need to find text, I'm using SUMPRODUCT in combination with ROW and INDEX.

Unfortunately when no cell is found, my SUMPRODUCT returns 0. This causes the formula to return the incorrect cell rather than blank. For this reason I am running the result through this calculation:

```
(1 / result)^-1
```

This way results of 0 become an error, and other results remain unchanged. I feed this into IFERROR, so that errors become blanks.

Does anyone know how to make this neater? I am not able to create new columns in any of my spreadsheets.

Comment: if it's functioning correctly, I wouldn't necessarily change it.  The only thing you'd probably change is how you test for 0 and it wouldn't make it simpler or easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always best to avoid using multi-condition summing functions like `SUMPRODUCT` when you want to find a single value (it would obviously give you an incorrect result or error if there's more than one row which matches all three conditions, I assume you expect one match at most here?). `ROW` function can also be problematic if you insert any rows in the worksheet.....

There are several approaches that can work. For a single formula, using `MATCH` is the most common - `MATCH` will only give the correct position or an error so no problems with zero values. That would look like this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(rangeOfDesiredValues,MATCH(1,(rangeOfSerials=$D20)*(rangeOfApps=cfgAppID)*(rangeOfAccessIDs=cfgAccessID),0)),"")`

That's an "array formula" that needs to be entered with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`......or you can make it into a regular formula with an extra INDEX function like this

`=IFERROR(INDEX(rangeOfDesiredValues,MATCH(1,INDEX((rangeOfSerials=$D20)*(rangeOfApps=cfgAppID)*(rangeOfAccessIDs=cfgAccessID),0),0)),"")`

A third alternative is to use LOOKUP which doesn't need "array entry"

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(rangeOfSerials=$D20)/(rangeOfApps=cfgAppID)/(rangeOfAccessIDs=cfgAccessID),rangeOfDesiredValues),"")`

That differs slightly from the previous versions in the case of multiple matches - it will give you the **last** match rather than the first in that scenario (but I assume you have only one match at most, as stated above).

Finally, if you don't mind using helper columns you could simplify the formulas considerably. Just use a "helper" column to concatenate the three criteria columns separated by dashes and then you can use a simple VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH, e.g.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(rangeOfDesiredValues,MATCH($D20&"-"&cfgAppID&"-"&cfgAccessID,Helper_Column,0)),"")`

Comment: Fairly deserved +1 for the efforts. Many useful things for myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful response!